# Setting Marquee on dynamically created textview?

Tags: android

I have created marquee `textview` by giving properties in xml. but when I create `textview` on runtime `with the same property` then the text does not scroll. I have written below code. Has anybody face this problem?

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setText("This is marquee text it should scroll");
 textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
 textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 textView.setFreezesText(true);
 textView.setSingleLine(true);
 textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
 textView.setFocusable(true);
 textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on my Galaxy Nexus (working on Jelly Bean), and it works fine. Could you give more detail information about your test setting?

Ah, one thing I added is layout param to ensure the width of view is shorter than text itself.

```
    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Animation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(START_POS_X, END_POS_X, 
                START_POS_Y, END_POS_Y);
mAnimation.setDuration(TICKER_DURATION); 
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

        TextView tvTitulo = new TextView(this);
        tvTitulo.setText("Some loooooooooooooooooooooong text");
        tvTitulo.setAnimation(mAnimation);


jUST CHECK this code .....
```

Comment: Textview's text gets cut at the end while displayed which is fine(as per the view width), but the animation also shows the truncated text for animation instead of full text.Can you please tell me why? If i set textview.setselected to true then full text shows up in the animation but the animation starts without user interaction.